# program in C language calculates the number of repeat words

Tags: c

I have a text file containing 5 words, and the second text file containing 2000 words I want to write a program in C language calculates the number of repeat words from first file in the second file and print the result on screen and I am new in C language , can any one help me to do it ...Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int read_line(FILE *in, char *buffer, size_t max)
{
  return fgets(buffer, max, in) == buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    char b[2000];
    int wcount = 0;
    int j;
    char i[5];                       
    char File_path[40];
    char stuff[5] = "False";
    FILE *file1;
    FILE *file2;


   file1=fopen("test.txt", "r");                // my word list text file
   file2=fopen("dickens-chimes-379.txt","r");   // my text file

    for (j = 0; j < 5 && strcmp(i, stuff); j++)
    {
     fscanf(file1,"%s",i);
     while (fgets(b,2000, file2)!=NULL)
         {
           if((strcat(b,i)) ==NULL)   
             {    
              wcount=0;
             }
           wcount++;
         }
      printf("%s     %d\n",i,wcount);
      wcount=0;
    }
fclose(file1);
fclose(file2);
}
```

my input is (test.txt) have words (love,like,book,go, and test)
the output is love 4296 like 0 book 0 go 0 test 0

i need the real value of the words occurrence in file2

Comment: char stuff[5] = "False"; is not null terminated. strcmp's with it will go haywire.

Comment: Also, check your return values from fopen.

Comment: Can't you search again and find code that does *exactly* what you need? Gosh, don't they teach you *nothing* these days?

Comment: I did this work... I understood the strategy for structure the program because I use object c and I made programs in another language ,but in c I don't know the function that can help me to do the comparison .I work on servers, my teacher asked me to do this program quickly and I haven't enough time to learn c language and he told me to ask in this web site....

Answer (score 1):

> i found this code in the net and i don't know how to modify it because
>   i an new to c language .. i hope you could help to to write code for
>   same thing

I feel to mention that this is a fairly complicated problem for a beginner. I would suggest to get warmed up with simpler problems first.

Nevertheless, here are some high level thoughts:

- Separate I/O from business logic

  Read test.txt in a array of 5 words

  Read a dickens.txt in a character array.
  [If the file is really really big, then this strategy may need to be modified.]
- Pass the test array and dickens array to the core function, say repeatFinder()

Very very high level pseudocode:

```
for each word w in test array:
    scan dickens array
    if w occurs in dickens:
        w_counter +=1
    advance dickens array
```

In C, you can use `strstr( dickens, w )`  [[link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html)] to find if `w` is present in `dickens`

Comment: I did this work... I understood the strategy for structure the program because I use object c and I made programs in another language ,but in c I don't know the function that can help me to do the comparison .I work on servers, my teacher asked me to do this program quickly and I haven't enough time to learn c language and he told me to ask in this web site.... char b[2000]; my first array that include the dickens file , char I[5] words array , strcat(b,i)) the comparison. But when I run it, not get the true values... so I need small help to chick where is my fault... Thank you for all